# Error while mapping Page<ObjectEntity> to Page<ObjectDTO> in spring boot new version

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper, mapper

I have this below piece of code and it's now working after moving to new version of spring i.e. 2.1.5 RELEASE 
Kindly,  help with this -

Prior, I have a version of 1.5.7 version of Spring boot - Below is my `pom.xml` file of now and prior.

> Error: The method map(Function) in the type Page is not applicable for the
>   arguments (new Converter(){})

Pom.xml (Now):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <guava.version>28.0-jre</guava.version>
    <jwt.version>0.9.0</jwt.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.9</commons-lang.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.10.2</joda-time.version>
    <start-class>com.afcs</start-class>
</properties>
```

Pom.xml (Prior):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <guava.version>26.0-jre</guava.version>
    <jwt.version>0.9.0</jwt.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.7</commons-lang.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.10</joda-time.version>
    <start-class>com.afcs</start-class>
</properties>
```

---

```
    final Page<DutyAllocationDto> dutyAllocationDto = dutyAllocationBean
            .map(new Converter<DutyAllocationBean, DutyAllocationDto>() {
                @Override
                public DutyAllocationDto convert(DutyAllocationBean entity) {
                    DutyAllocationDto dto = new DutyAllocationDto();
                    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
                    dto = modelMapper.map(entity, DutyAllocationDto.class);
                    DutyAllocation dutyAllocation = dutyAllocationFilterRepository
                            .findById(entity.getDutyallocationid()).get();
                    if (dutyAllocation != null) {
                        dto.setCityName(dutyAllocation.getTblDepotMaster().getCityMaster().getCityName());
                    }
                    if(dto.getRoutenumber()!=null)
                    {
                    Tblroutemaster route=tblroutemasterRepository.findByrouteNumber(Long.valueOf(dto.getRoutenumber()));
                    if(route!=null)
                    {
                        dto.setRouteName(route.getRouteName());
                    }
                    }

                    return dto;
                }

            });
```

Comment: Please follow this https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application. It may help you.

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan I require conditional mapping as you can see in the above-mentioned code. It doesn't explain conditional mapping.